# How can I cast while doing a division assignment?

Tags: c

I am practicing C basics for my exam and encountered a tricky situation while doing a simple `for` loop:

```
int main()
{
    for( double i = 9.999; i > 0; )
    {
        printf("%d ", ((int)i) /= 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
         printf("%d ", ((int)i) /= 2);
                                ^~
```

Isn't `(int)i` an lvalue? Or how could you rewrite it to get the output: `4 2 1 0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't `(int)i` an lvalue ?

`i` is, `(int)i` isn't.

> Or how could you rewrite it to get the output: `4 2 1 0`?

The best you can do is be clear and separate the statements:

```
i = (int)i / 2;
printf("%d ", (int)i);
```

Note that you cannot use `i /= 2` in the first one since then you will not get to zero quickly by truncating.

Answer (score 3):

`i` by itself is an lvalue but `(int)i` is not.  The result of the typecast operator is not an lvalue.

You'll need to break up the compound assignment operator:

```
printf("%d ",(int)(i =(int)i/2));
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach, even though it is a little bit tricky to do all at once, because the OP´s question is "*How can I cast **while** doing a division assignment?*"

Answer (score 2):

A cast expression like `(int)i` is NOT an lvalue but rather an rvalue.

For readability, just update the value of `i` on a different line.:

```
...
i /= 2;
printf("%d ", (int)i);
...
```